# Crash while accessing any member of the PE's PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY structure

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, portable-executable

I'm trying to get the RVA of a function in `kernel32.dll` and I got the offset for the export directory and added it with my `file_map`. However when I try to do anything with any of the members of the `PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` structure, my program crashes. I can't even check whether or not it's a `nullptr` without it crashing. Here is my code:

```
#include "Sample.h" //Just contains other headers
#include <dbghelp.h>
#include <imagehlp.h>

int main()
{
    char kernel_path[MAX_PATH];

    //PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDos_hdr = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
    //if(pDos_hdr == NULL){printf("Invalid header: %d", (int)GetLastError());}

    if(GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), kernel_path, MAX_PATH) == 0)
    {
        printf("GetModuleFileName failed: %d", (int)GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(kernel_path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
       NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){printf("Error getting file handle: 
       %d", (int)GetLastError());return 1;}

    HANDLE kernel_map = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, 
       PAGE_READONLY|SEC_IMAGE, 0, 256, "KernelMap");

    LPVOID file_map = MapViewOfFile(kernel_map, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    if(file_map == 0){printf("Error getting mapped view: %d",
      (int)GetLastError());return 1;}

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDos_hdr = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)file_map;
    if(pDos_hdr->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE){printf("Has MZ signature\n");}

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNt_hdr = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((char*)file_map+pDos_hdr->e_lfanew);
    if(pNt_hdr->Signature == 0x4550){printf("Has PE signature\n");}

    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER opt_hdr = pNt_hdr->OptionalHeader;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY exp_entry = 
       opt_hdr.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT];
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY pExp_dir = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)
        (((char*)file_map)+exp_entry.VirtualAddress);

    // Crashing Code --->
    void **func_table = (void**)((char*)file_map+pExp_dir->AddressOfFunctions);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx), **CreateFileMapping**::
>   *dwMaximumSizeLow [in]* -
>
> The low-order DWORD of the maximum size of the file mapping object. If
>   this parameter and dwMaximumSizeHigh are 0 (zero), the maximum size of
>   the file mapping object is equal to the current size of the file that
>   hFile identifies.

You haven't mapped the full size of the file to the current process's virtual memory. This is because you have limited (`256`) the [dwMaximumSizeLow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) parameter of the [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) function. You can verify that by calling [VirtualQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
HANDLE kernel_map = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, 
PAGE_READONLY|SEC_IMAGE, 0, 0, "KernelMap"); // 5th Param = 0
```

Comment: That's what I get for glancing over function documentation. Much appreciated!

Comment: Happens to best of us :)